# Updating one formControl in angular6 should update Other and vice versa

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript2.0

I'm having 2 select menus(with same options) in my UI. If I select menu option in first Select menu then the other select menu should be reflected with the same option and vice versa.

Currently I used the valueChanges method on first formControl to update the second.
If I use the same for the second form control also then I will get "Maximum call stack size exceeded" Error.

So please suggest how can update both the select menu when value changes on either of them.

Code looks as below.

Form Controls used are:

```
// Form group for Simple Search
this.simpleSearchForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      orderType: [''],
      searchBy: [''],
      searchCriteria: ['']
    });

// Form Group for Advanced Search
    this.advancedSearchForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      orderType: [''],
      searchBydateField: [''],
      dateRangeFrom: [''],
      dateRangeTo: [''],
      filterResultsBy: ['']

    });
```

For Changing the Advanced form Control.

```
//Change in simple form should reflect the change in advanced form
    this.simpleSearchForm.get('orderType').valueChanges.subscribe(data => {
      this.advancedSearchForm.get('orderType').setValue(this.simpleSearchForm.get('orderType').value);
    });
```

Also attached the snapshot of both the Select menus.[image: Select Menus]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use angular `change` event to update the values.

```
in component.ts

 changeSecondFormValue(){
    this.advancedSearchForm.controls['secondFormValue'].seValue(this.simpleSearchForm.get('firstFormValue').value)
 }
```

in component.html

```
 //select 1 form Form 1
<select (change)="changeSecondFormValue()" formControlName="firstFormValue">
 <option value="1">option 1 </option>
 <option value="2">option 1 </option>
</select>

 //select 1 form Form 1
<select  formControlName="secondvalue">
 <option value="1">option 1 </option>
 <option value="2">option 1 </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the update.
One Thing I forgot is I'm using the primeng dropdown(p-dropdown), So i used (onChange) event.

Answer (score 0):

Normal Select is using for the menus then (change) event will works.
If other than the normal select if any other select menu of other 3rd parties is used then depending on the third parties we need to bind the select menu for changes.

Ex: I used Primeng, So I need to use (onChange) event for the select menu.

Code for both normal and prime ng select

### Normal

In html

```
<select (change)="changeSecondFormValue()" formControlName="orderType">
<option value="1">option 1 </option>
 <option value="2">option 1 </option>
</select>
```

In Component

```
changeSecondFormValue(): void {
 this.simpleSearchForm.get('orderType').setValue(this.advancedSearchForm.get('orderType').value);
}
```

### For Prime Ng

In Html

```
<p-dropdown name="orderType" id="orderType" [options]="orderTypes"
                      formControlName="orderType" optionLabel="orderTypeName"
                      (onChange) = "changeValueFromAdvanced()"></p-dropdown>
```

In Component

```
changeValueFromAdvanced() {
    this.advancedSearchForm.get('orderType').setValue(this.simpleSearchForm.get('orderType').value);
}
```